# Unable to render canvas or run script in react-native android webview

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am trying to render `Chart.js` charts in my webview in react-native application. 
But neither I am able to do `postMessage` or render the canvas chart.
I think my function in script tag itself is not working could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

PS: I tried to check if atleast `postmessage` might work using `injectJavascrpt` option in `webview` even that is not sending any message on my webview.

Here is the component code I have written to plot the chart

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { WebView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'

class WebViewGraph extends Component {
  state = {
    init: `
      <html>
        <head>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"/>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div>
          <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
          <h1>hello</h1>
          <p>gyfgyg</p>
          </div>
        <script>
          function abc() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d"); 
            var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
                gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(250,174,50,1)');   
                gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(250,174,50,0)');
            var data = {
                        labels : ["02:00","04:00","06:00","08:00","10:00","12:00","14:00","16:00","18:00","20:00","22:00","00:00"],
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                fillColor : gradient, // Put the gradient here as a fill color
                                strokeColor : "#ff6c23",
                                pointColor : "#fff",
                                pointStrokeColor : "#ff6c23",
                                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                                pointHighlightStroke: "#ff6c23",
                                data : [25.0,32.4,22.2,39.4,34.2,22.0,23.2,24.1,20.0,18.4,19.1,17.4]
                            }
                        ]
                    };
            var options = {
                responsive: true,
                datasetStrokeWidth : 3,
                pointDotStrokeWidth : 4,
                tooltipFillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
                tooltipFontStyle: "bold",
                tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label + ' hod' %>: <%}%><%= value + '°C' %>",
                scaleLabel : "<%= Number(value).toFixed(0).replace('.', ',') + '°C'%>"
            };
            var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
            window.postMessage('Hello there')
          }
          abc()
        </script>
        </body>
      </html>`
  }

  onMessage = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  }

  render() {
    const str = `${this.state.init}`
    return (
      <View style={styles.full}>
        <WebView
          style={styles.full}
          source={{ html: str, baseUrl: 'web/' }}
          javaScriptEnabled
          domStorageEnabled
          scalesPageToFit
          scrollEnabled={false}
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets
          onMessage={this.onMessage}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  full: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#c3c3c3'
  }
})

export default WebViewGraph
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your `script` tag with a separate tag, i.e. `<script src="..."></script>`. Dumb but true. From there, you should start seeing errors in your JavaScript console if you have any related to your `Chart.js` usage.

Comment: yes that solved my issue after more than 5 hours of pointless debugging. Thanks :), but the errors I am still not seeing related to `chartjs` or any javascript errors in console, it just renders white/empty webview

Comment: I'd suggest copying and pasting just your HTML/JS w/fixed script tag into a .html file on your computer and loading up that file in Chrome, then opening the console for that webpage. You should see error(s) output then. Guessing you don't in the RN app because the console errors are printing to that web view's console.